# Shift data of one li & ul tag from one div class tag to another div id tag without any li & ul tags just only data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my code below:

```
<div id="title">
      <span><b>Title</b></span>
</div>

<div class="data">
    <ul>
            <li id="cp_name" class=""><span>Name:</span> XXXX</li>
            <li id="cp_dept" class=""><span>Dept:</span> Editing</li>
            <li id="cp_role" class=""><span>Role:</span> YYYY</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Original Output**

**Title**

- Name: XXXX
- Dept: Editing
- Role: YYYY

**Expected Output & Code**

**Title**

Dept: Editing

- Name: XXXX
- Role: YYYY

  ```
  <div id="title">
     <span><b>Title</b></span>
        <div id="cp_dept">
           <span>Dept:</span> Editing
        </div>
  </div>

  <div class="data">
   <ul>
       <li id="cp_name" class=""><span>Name:</span> XXXX</li>
       <li id="cp_role" class=""><span>Role:</span> YYYY</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  ```

I want to extract or just remove li & ul tags of "cp_dept" i.e Dept: Editing data from div class="data" & wan't to shift data into div id="title" tag without li & ul tags i.e just only data as shown in Expected Output & Code that too with immediate effect on page loading.

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QqNBC/) , check this out.

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zkP7j/)**

Try this code..

```
var li=$('.data>ul>li').eq(1).remove();
var id=li.attr('id');
var html=li.html();
var div1=$('<div></div>').attr('id',id).append(html);
$('#title').append(div1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```javascript
var dept = $(".data ul li#cp_dept").html();
dept = "<div id='cp_dept'>" + dept + "</div>";
$("#title").append(dept);
$(".data ul li#cp_dept").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use insertAfter jQuery function : (remove and append)

```
$(function() {
    $('#cp_dept').insertAfter('#title span');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#cp_dept').detach().wrapInner('<div />').contents().unwrap().appendTo('#title');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7gpVP/)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this javascript only answer

**JS**

```
(function() {
     var dpt = document.getElementById('cp_dept');
     dpt.outerHTML=""
     var tit = document.getElementById('title');
     tit.innerHTML = tit.innerHTML +"<br>"+dpt.textContent;
  })();
```

*[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fUDP3/2/)*

Just added or edited a line in the Javascript. Instead of removing or editing cp_dept, I assign the CSS to `display:none`. It does the same function but this way I'm not erasing the contents of the cp_dept tag and hence the HTML markup remains intact.

```
(function() {
     var dpt = document.getElementById('cp_dept');
    // dpt.outerHTML=""
     dpt.style.display="none";
     var tit = document.getElementById('title');
     tit.innerHTML = tit.innerHTML +"<br>"+dpt.textContent;
  })();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var htm = $("#cp_dept").text();
$("#data ul #cp_dept").remove();
$("#title").append('<div id="cp_dept">'+htm+'</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var getli = $('.data #cp_dept');
    $('.data #cp_dept').remove();    
    $creDiv = $('<div />').attr('id',getli.attr('id'))
                          .html(getli.html());
    $("#title").append($creDiv);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4pVHz/5/)

But you may be looking for more, please comment on it

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new element to append the "cp_dept" target, then add the new element to "#title".

```
var title = document.getElementById('title');
var dept = document.getElementById('cp_dept');

var newDept = document.createElement('div');
newDept.innerHTML = dept.innerHTML;

// remove the old cp_dept
dept.parentNode.removeChild(dept);

title.appendChild(newDept);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("li#cp_dept").each(function(){

var div = $("<div id='"+$(this).attr("id")+"'/>");

div.html($(this).html());

div.appendTo("div#title");

$(this).remove();

});
```